# How can I define default where condition for all select queries in my models?

Tags: mysql, laravel, model, eloquent, default

I need to set a default where condition in my models.

So actually i have to set it in my all select queries.

**Query like:**

```
->where('status','active')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use laravel scope (local scope or global scope )in model:

**Global scope Example :**

In Model.php:

```
 protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();    
        static::addGlobalScope('status', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('status', 'active');
        });
    }
```

**Local Scope Example :**

In Model.php

```
public function scopeIsActive($query)
    {
        return $query->where('status', 'active');
    }
```

in controller :

```
Model::isActive()->get();
```

[source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes)

Comment: Can be apply isActive() scope on all queries globally without applying for each query in controller?

Comment: @khalidJ-A for that you can create global scope.

Answer (score 3):

You should try this:

Your model:

```
class News extends Eloquent {
   public function scopeStatus($query)
    {
     return $query->where('status', '=', 1);
    }
 }
```

Your Controller:

```
$news  = News::status()->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Global Scope:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#global-scopes

Write it in your model you want to query with condition

```
/**
 * The "booting" method of the model.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('status', function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->where('status', 'active');
    });
}
```